# IE8 issue with loading FLASH. SWF loads and renders correctly on initial load, but on any subsequent refresh it fails to load

Tags: internet-explorer-8, flash

I need some help? Anyone experience this problem before with IE8 FLASH bug? Can not get this to work on all subsequent refresh to the flash. I have a flash piece which simply renders only on the first initial load. After that, if i refresh or visit the page, it does not load correctly. It seems I am having this problem with the swf only on subsequent loading of the page or whenever a refresh happens. Can you offer any ideas or services to help?

Comment: is this flash piece an animated swf with last frame blank?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen, on a number of occasions, issues like this occurring due to logical errors with pre-loaders.

Do you have a pre-loader?

If you do, how is it determining if the movie is loaded? Are you expecting a particular event to fire, which might have fired before you listen for it? Can you test to see if the movie is already loaded, before going into the preloader?

Hopefully you have a preloader... otherwise this answer is useless.